# Using Boto to determine if an AWS AMI is available

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am using Boto to create an AMI of one of my EC2 boxes, and then I would like to spin up more boxes with that AMI, but the `run_instances` command is barking that my AMI is not available yet.

How can I use boto to query aws to find out when my ami is ready?

The EC2 connection supports a method to [get_image](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_image)

But the [Image](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.image) does not have any sort of status attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a quick [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) of Image led me to `Image.state` with values like `"pending"` and `"available"`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "pending" and "available" there is also the "failed" state.  This is the full set of AMI states available.

Answer (score 0):

I can write a simple function using boto3

```
def check_ami_exists(ami_id, region): 
  client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = region)
  response = client.describe_images()
  for image in response['Images']:
    if ami_id == image['ImageId']:
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the above method but it took a little while for me to figure it out. Not a python person but here is what I did. Hope it helps someone.

```
#EC2 Connection
conn = boto.ec2.connect()

image_status = conn.get_all_images(image_ids='ami-XXX')[0]
image_state = image_status.state
print image_state
```